# OpenLayers 2.x app: Google tiles stopped displaying

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

A user of my website http://rainpursuit.org/map.htm alerted me that the Google Base tiles are no longer showing up.  I've got the following code to add the Google Terrain tiles:

```
       var physical = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Physical",
            {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN}
        );
```

Doesn't anybody know Google Changed anything with their API.  Got some replacement code that I could paste in?  Or any links on how to upgrade and API and get it to work in OL 2.13.1?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335221/google-maps-api-change)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my post is pretty much a duplicate of the post that geocodezip pointed out in the comment above.  Thanks for leading me to a very quick and easy fix. For the record, I DID do a somewhat thorough search of StackOverflow before I posted my issue.

As pointed out in the link that geocodezip provided, changing to Google Map API version 3.20 quickly fixed my problems.  Awesome.  Thanks!